# How To: Register ServiceStack's Redis Client Manager singleton in ASP.NET Core using the default container

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, asp.net-core-2.0, servicestack.redis

I've been reading several documents and articles on how to ServiceStack's Redis client, but all of them use the ServiceStack's `AppHost` method and their built-in Func IOC
But I don't want to mix different IOC containers in my project.
And besides I don't want to use any other ServiceStack component other than the Redis client. Therefore I wanted to inject a singleton instance of the `IRedisClientsManager` preferably through the `RedisManagerPool` factory, straight from the `ConfigureServices` method of **Startup.cs**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a reviewing the code from the updated [.NET Core Live Demos](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/LiveDemos)
I figured out a clean and simple way of doing it.

So in my `ConfigureServices` method I registered `IRedisClientsManager` like this

```
services.AddSingleton<IRedisClientsManager> (c =>
              new RedisManagerPool(Configuration.GetSection("Redis-Host").Value));
```

of course in order to read from configuration in ConfigureServices you need to add a constructor to inject it to Startup

```
IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;
```